# Origin of the "white feather as a symbol of cowardice"

Tags: phrase-origin, metaphors, allusion

I’m researching the origins of the white feather as a symbol of  cowardice. The earliest reference I can find is in Francis Grose’s 1785 Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue. Does anyone know of any earlier occurrences?

Comment: Is this question about using white feathers themselves as symbols or about the metaphorical use of the **phrase** *white feather*? The former would be outside the domain of this site.

Comment: Related: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/42520/when-was-the-white-feather-first-used-as-a-symbol-of-cowardice

Answer (score 2):

The OED uses Grose's dictionary as its first source and adds

> 1. A white feather as a symbol of cowardice. [...]**With allusion to the fact that a white feather in a game bird's tail was considered a mark of inferior breeding.**
>
> 1785   F. Grose Classical Dict. Vulgar Tongue   *White feather, he has a white feather, he is a coward, an allusion to a game cock, where having a white feather, is a proof he is not of the true game breed.*

Grose's example, game cock/breed is a use of "**game**" in the hunting sense and OED **game**, adj. *1. Of a person or animal: full of pluck, spirit, or fight; spirited, plucky; intrepid. Also applied to actions, attributes, etc.*